# How does "set -e" work with subshells?

Tags: bash, error-handling, return-code

I was wondering whether `set -e` propagates through subshells (i.e. does a subshell inherit the `-e` setting of its parent), so I made some experiments. I found some strange results that I can't explain.

First, here are some basic tests. They return what I expect.

```
( true; false )         # 1
( false; true )         # 0
( set -e; false; true ) # 1
```

Now I tried what happens if I put a subshell within my subshell. This expression returns 1, which suggests that it propagates.

```
( set -e; ( false; true ) )
```

Then I tried these expressions. I expected them to return 1, but I found that they return 0.

```
( set -e; ( true; false ); true )
( set -e; ( set -e; false; true ); true )
```

Why? In both cases, the inner subshell returns 1, whether `set -e` propagates or not (as I checked in the beginning). The outer subshell has `set -e`, which means that it should fail after the inner subshell exits, but it does not. Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Prior to `bash` 4, `set -e` appears to only cause the shell to exit if a simple command has a non-zero exit (emphasis mine):

> -e      Exit  immediately  if  a  **simple command** (see SHELL GRAMMAR above) exits with a non-zero status.

In `bash` 4 (possibly 4.1, I don't have a 4.0 to check), the effect of `-e` was extended to more complicated commands:

> -e Exit immediately if a pipeline (which may consist of a single simple command),  a subshell  com-
>                         mand enclosed in parentheses, or one of the commands executed as part of a command list enclosed
>                         by braces (see SHELL GRAMMAR above) exits with a non-zero status.

Comment: Nicely done; as of bash 4.3.30, the wording is :"Exit  immediately if a pipeline  (which  may  consist of a single simple command), _a list, or a compound command_ (see SHELL GRAMMAR above),  exits with a non-zero status."

Answer (score 4):

From `man bash`:

> **set [+abefhkmnptuvxBCEHPT] [+o option-name] [arg ...]**
>
> **-e**
>
> **Exit immediately if a pipeline (which may consist of a single simple
>   command), a subshell command enclosed in parentheses, or one of the
>   commands executed as part of a command list enclosed by braces (see
>   SHELL GRAMMAR above)  exits  with  a non-zero  status**.  The shell does
>   not exit if the command that fails is part of the command list
>   immediately following a while or until keyword, part of the test
>   following the if or elif reserved words, part of any command executed
>   in a && or || list except the command following the final && or ||,
>   any command in a pipeline but the last, or if the command's return
>   value is being inverted with !.  A trap on ERR, if set, is executed
>   before the shell exits.  This  option  applies  to the shell
>   environment and each subshell environment separately (see COMMAND
>   EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT above), and may cause subshells to exit before
>   executing all the commands in the subshell.

So when a `false` is found, it exits from the subshell.

See a couple of examples:

```
# when `false`, exit. Hence, no `echo ho`
$ ( set -e; echo hi; false; echo ho ) ; echo $?
hi
1

# when `false`, exit. Hence, no `echo hu`
$ ( set -e; echo hi; true; echo ho; false; echo hu ) ; echo $?
hi
ho
1
```

Comment: I can see that the particular subshell exits but not the outer one, but it doesn't follow from the documentation that it should work like this. It seems to work this way though, so I have to plan my script this way.

Comment: Mmm don't know if I understand you properly. In inner sub-shells the parameter is replicated -> `( set -e; ( true; false; echo 22 ) ; echo 55 )` won't print either 22 nor 55.

Comment: In `bash` 3.2, the 55 is echoed. In `bash` 4.1, it is not. This is possibly the result of a bug fix in `bash` 4 or 4.1, although I can't find anything related in the `bash` release notes.

Comment: The wording for the `-e` option did change between 3.2 and 4. In 3.2, it only seems to apply to simple commands, not compound commands (like subshells) or pipelines and such.

Comment: It's even more complicated: If you directly (with a conditional on the expression itself, not on `$?`) test the return code of the subshell, that affects how that subshell behaves. It (bash 3) doesn't bail out. `( set -e; false; echo inner ); [ $? -eq 0 ] || echo outer` prints `outer`, `( set -e; false; echo inner ) || echo outer` prints `inner`.

Answer (score 4):

As of Bash 4.4, these commands all return `1`:

```
( set -e; ( false; true ) )
( set -e; ( true; false ); true )
( set -e; ( set -e; false; true ); true )
```

So I think you may be using an older version of Bash which has different implementations about `set -e` and subshell commands, as pointed out by [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22636016/418966).