# bash pipefail still running w/ set -e after command in process substitution fails

Tags: linux, bash

script.sh:

```
set -x
set -e
set -u
set -o pipefail

foo=$(tail -1 <(false || { >&2 echo "failed" && exit 1; }) | echo "pipeline still running" || { >&2 echo "failed" && exit 1; }) || { >&2 echo "failed" && exit 1; }

echo "Script still running..."
```

Why does `echo "Script still running..."` end up being executed? I thought the combination of `set -e` and `set -o pipefail` should mean that `false` gets propagated out to the main script and terminates at `foo=...` but instead foo is assigned "pipeline still running"... and the script continues when I wish it would not. I had thought [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22630363/how-does-set-e-work-with-subshells) supports that idea.

After reading the bash man page about pipefail (in particular), it states that `A pipeline is a sequence of one or more commands separated by one of the control operators ‘|’ or ‘|&’.`

I take it, then, that `set` does not propagate into subshells? Is there a way to have that occur?

For reference, I am using

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.46(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: ...by the way, while `pipefail` is generally regarded as a best practice, `set -e` is... [controversial](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105). [So is `set -u`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/112).

Comment: and, err, just to be very clear -- a process substitution (`<(...)`) is not a regular subshell `(...)`). Yes, it runs in a subshell, but something you read talking about subshells in general probably won't have process substitution in mind.

Comment: I knew about `set -u` being "controversial". Frankly I think the arguments against it are boring and unenlightened: I find it highly useful to help ensure that I didn't accidentally typo something. I think `set -e` and `set -o pipefail` are both symptoms of Bash being a poor choice when you need to be sensitive to errors. Ultimately my goal is "if anything doesn't make sense to the computer, then it doesn't make sense to me, and the script should _stop_ and report the error". Thanks for the heads up though. Process substitution is effectively a subshell but using a named pipe instead, right?

Comment: If your concern is typos, that's what static checking is for -- http://shellcheck.net/ is not just a website but a [downloadable, installable piece of software](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck).

Comment: ...and yes, "effectively a subshell but a named pipe" is an reasonably effective one-sentence description of process substitution -- one just needs to be careful about how far one draws the parallel; it's effectively a *background* process, not required to exit before the shell goes on to the next command.

Comment: Consider the case where you're passing a process-substitution-generated named pipe (or /dev/fd handle) to a command that's self-daemonizing: That process substitution can still be running, so that the self-backgrounded part of the process can read from it, even after the foreground part has returned and the shell has proceeded forward.

Comment: As for `set -e`, the core of the problem is that it's a kludge: exit status semantics aren't at their core identical to exception handling behavior, and not all nonzero exits indicate errors. Without a way to return "this program is successfully returning a result of false to its caller", you end up with increasingly complicated semantics, such as the "`set -e` is ignored in a checked context" rule that wreaks havoc when `yourfunc && dosomething` means that the whole of `yourfunc` is considered checked. And yet these rules are enshrined in POSIX, and changing them breaks compatibility.

Comment: ...so instead of throwing the rules out, you get *more rules* layered on top of them: Okay, we're following the POSIX rules, but trying to add all these exceptions in undefined space (or when a flag is set) to eliminate the surprises... at which point it's even *harder* to know what `set -e` will do in a given situation, especially if you want your code to behave reliably across multiple shell releases (let alone future revisions with yet more kludges still not written!), or to be used as a library from code that may or may not set the optional behavior-changing flags.

Comment: ...so, if you want to talk about "enlightened" lanugage design? I'm on the LISP side of the world: Simplicity and obviousness are golden -- and while behavior with `set -e` may *look* simple and obvious, once you dig into the details, it's nothing of the sort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing to do with pipefail.

```
cat <(exit 1)
```

...has an exit status of 0, with or without `pipefail` set: Process substitutions are not pipeline components, and their exit status is not checked.

That said, in bash 4.4 and later you *can* check it explicitly as follows:

```
cat <(exit 1); pid=$!
wait "$pid" # this will have the exit status of the process substitution operation
```

---

Incidentally, there are compelling reasons for this. Consider:

```
exec 3< <(echo hello; exit 1)
read greeting <&3
echo "Greeting is: $greeting"
```

Now, *which command* would you expect to fail? It can't be the one where the redirection from a process substitution is actually performed, because the process substitution remains active beyond that single command's execution, and until a `read` has occurred, the process substitution *hasn't failed yet*.

It wouldn't reliably be `read greeting`, because that read *succeeds* -- it's only *after* the write associated with that read has completed that the process on the other end of the pipeline fails, and it's not guaranteed that that `exit` has or has not happened before the outer shell has gone on to the final `echo`.

Comment: What if I have two process substitutions in one command. For example.
`diff <(...) <(...)` and I want to make sure that both commands are successfully executed?

Comment: @Fefer_Ivan, then you need to start them independently, on separate commands. If you're having trouble doing that, feel free to @-notice me on a question you raise about it.