# How can one prevent a bash script continuing on error when using eval or command substitution

Tags: bash, shell, command-substitution

I have a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'

# Run a command
eval $(mycommand)

# Run another command
anothercommand
```

This script is called via SSH as follows:

`ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p 22 -l ${USER_NAME} ${HOST_NAME} './run.sh'`

I have noticed that if the first command (inside the eval) fails, e.g. the command `mycommand` isn't on the path execution continues to the next step.

I'd like to prevent this. I thought that's what the `set -euo pipefail` was achieving. I presume it's something to do with the `eval` or use of `$()`.

Is there a way to stop execution if the first command fails.

Comment: It should be `eval "${mycommand}"` - braces not parentheses

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22636016/450611

Note that process substitution (`$()`) is not among the list of affected features.

Comment: @hek2mgl thanks, when you say it should, you mean to achieve my desired behaviour? It currently "works" in as much as it runs the commands. Do you know the reason why it should be this way - am I right to say the latter is called "parameter substitution" rather than "command substitution".

Comment: `$(command)` is a command substituion. It expands to the output of command and passes that output to `eval`. Not sure if you want that. Actually I doubt that you want to use `eval` at all.

Comment: Replace `eval $(mycommand)` with `mycommand || { echo "MyMessage"; exit 1; }` and remove the `set -e`. Or does the `ssh` call has a hidden argument with the command?

Comment: @hek2mgl I think I do want the eval. The inner command is an `aws ecr get-login` command which print to stdout the `docker login` command that you should run. In this case I want the `docker login` command to actually be run. The subsequent other commands rely first on the login - hence why I really want to abort if step 1 fails

Comment: When I run the command with ${} instead of $() I get: `-su: ${aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region eu-west-1}: bad substitution`

Comment: I see. Your question should have been clear about that.